# Jquery JTable Load from 2 Tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using Jquery-JTable in my website to load details in a grid view and to let user be able to modify, delete app accordingly.

I am loading data successfully from 2 tables and then display them in my div. Now the user would like to modify a record accordingly to his/her wish.

I would like to let the user choose from a dropdown list obtained from another table. Can this be done?

Code Below: As you can see I am loading data from multiple tables using InnerJoin. For example I would like to let the user choose another Category or Language etc.

```
$queryString = "SELECT `app_id`,`app_name`,`app_type`,`app_url`,`AppAccepted`,`BenefitApp`, application_ageGroup.ageGroup,application_category.category, application_Country.country,application_Language.language FROM application INNER JOIN application_ageGroup ON application.ageGroup_id = application_ageGroup.ageGroup_id INNER JOIN application_category ON application.Category = application_category.category_id INNER JOIN application_Country ON application.country_id = application_Country.country_id INNER JOIN application_Language ON application.language_id = application_Language.language_id ORDER BY $jtSorting LIMIT $jtStartIndex,$jtPageSize";
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Make the Category column as dropdown and bind it with your query dataset :

```
$('#Table').jtable({
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 200,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Category ASC',
        selecting: false,
        multiselect: false,
        selectingCheckboxes: false,
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Application/GetData',
            updateAction: '/Application/EditData'
        },
        fields: {
            Category: {
                title: 'Category',
                width: '10%',
                list: false,
                sorting: true,
                options: '/Application/GetCategories'
            }
        });
```

In your controller action, fetch Category lists:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCategories()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtCategories = new DataTable();

            string query = "SELECT .....";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                dtCategories.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
            }

            List<Store> categoryList = DatatableToGenericList(dtCategories);

            var categories = categoryList.Select(category => new { DisplayText = category.Name , Value = category.Id }).OrderBy(s => s.DisplayText);

            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = categories });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

private static List<Store> DatatableToGenericList(DataTable table)
    {
        var categoryList = new List<Category>(table.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var values = row.ItemArray;
            var store = new Category()
            {
                Id = values[0].ToString(),
                Name = values[1].ToString()
            };
            categoryList.Add(store);
        }

        return categoryList;
    }
```

Category Model

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps..